# How to Route to Feature Module

Tags: angular

I'm trying to have a route from one module include a component from another module. The scheme I'm trying to implement is: `/group/feature` which should show the content in feature.html included in the content of group.html where the router-outlet is. I can get `/group` to work, but `/group/feature` returns `page not found`.

The full project is available here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nsfgyr

Here are the main files:

feature.module.ts:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  declarations: [FeatureComponent],
  exports: [FeatureComponent]
})
export class FeatureModule {
}
```

group-module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FeatureModule,
    GroupRoutingModule,
  ],
  declarations: [
    GroupComponent,
  ],
  exports: [GroupComponent]
})
export class GroupModule {
}
```

group-routing.module.ts:

```
const ingestRoutes: Routes = [
  {path: 'feature', component: FeatureComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(ingestRoutes)
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})
export class GroupRoutingModule {
}
```

app-routing.module:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'group'},
    {path: 'group', component: GroupComponent},
    {path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent}
  ]
;

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(
      routes,
      {enableTracing: false, useHash: false}
    )
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
}
```

Comment: Take a look here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9f3ssu, updated routes in group-routing-module

Comment: Thanks @Deshak9, but when I go to `/group/feature` it only renders feature.html. I'm trying to get it to render the content in groupl.html with feature.html included in the router-outlet. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first way. No children, no modules imported.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'group'},
  {path: 'group/feature', component: FeatureComponent },
  {path: 'group', component: GroupComponent},
  {path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
  RouterModule.forRoot(routes,
  {enableTracing: false, useHash: false}
  )
],
exports: [
  RouterModule
]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
}
```

The second way is to use children..

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'group'},
  {path: 'group', component: GroupComponent,
   children: [
    { path: 'feature', component: FeatureComponent }]     
  },
  {path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent}
];
```

The third way is to import the module. It has its own

```
"<router-outlet></router-outlet>".

const ingestRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'group/feature', component: FeatureComponent,
    children: [       
      path: 'more', component: MoreComponent, // if you want to add..
        // this will route to group/feature/more
      path: '', component: FeatureHomeComponent,
    ] 
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(ingestRoutes)
  ],
  declarations: [
      FeatureComponent, FeatureHomeComponent, MoreComponent
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})
export class GroupRoutingModule {
}
```

The FeatureComponent.html has only

```
<route-outlet></router-outlet>.
```

FeatureHomeComponent.html

```
- you can display anything here..YOUR ACTURE FEATURE COMPONENT.HTML
```

Export this in AppRoutingModule.

```
 const routes: Routes = [
    {path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'group'},
    {path: 'group', component: GroupComponent},
    {path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent}
  ];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {enableTracing: false, useHash: 
    false}), GroupRoutingModule, // add this..
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
}
```

All I do for 'apple brand' is to just import AppleRoutingModule in my AppRoutingModule. See link.[Angular 4 route selection for category/subcategory or category/item for ecommerce web site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49221689/angular-4-route-selection-for-category-subcategory-or-category-item-for-ecommerc)

Comment: Let me know and I will try to help you further in routing.

Comment: Your children approach is what I was looking for -- Thank you

Comment: Glad to help. Happy Coding.

Answer (score 2):

You have defined the route for `'group'`. You haven't defined the route `'group/feature'`.

Update:

Your group route looks like a plain route to /group, but group is actually a child module and you don't load the component, you `loadChildren`.

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'group'},
    {path: 'group', loadChildren: 'app/group/group.module#GroupModule},
    {path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent}
  ]
;
```

Comment: Won't the `feature` routing on group-routing.module.ts do that?

Comment: @Brian. You should be able to just go to "feature" based on your code.  Just include a <route-outlet></router-outlet> for each module. There are so many ways in implementing lazy loading.

Comment: @Brian. The link below does not directly answer your question. But when I route to electronics, the path is just path: 'electronic', when I route to 'apple', the path is just path="apple". Electronic and Apple has its own routing module with their own router outlet imported to appRouting module.  I am just trying to help you.  Angular 4 route selection for category/subcategory or category/item for ecommerce web site. I will try to answer your question the best I can.

Comment: I implemented your suggestion here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zmwgff?file=app/group/group.html . Now `/group/feature` renders feature.html and `/group` renders nothing. I'd like `/group/feature` to include the content in group.html and include feature.html's content in the router-outlet tag. Is this possible?

Comment: Not sure about that. They are components in separate modules. When I try to add a parent module component selector in child module html template in a project of mine, I get an error that the component is not part of the module. I can get that same error in your stackblitz link (Thanks for that, BTW. Tried a few things, but didn't get anywhere).

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out: Adding the feature path in the children array of the group router worked:

In group-routing.module.ts:

```
const ingestRoutes: Routes = [
  {path: 'group', component: GroupComponent,
   children: [
     {path: 'feature', component: FeatureComponent}
  ]},
];
```

Thank you for all the responses and help!