# Is there a disavantage of using only one module? Should I separate in multiple?

Tags: angular, angular5

Currently in my project I have only the AppModule and I'm doing everything in it, and it is easy to understand and easy to do the routing.

They are all in the app module, but are all in their own folders:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CoreModule } from './core/core.module';
import { Angular2TokenService } from 'angular2-token';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app.routing';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { SignInComponent } from './auth/sign-in/sign-in.component';
import { UpdatePasswordComponent } from './auth/update_password/update_password.component';

import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { MaterialModule } from './shared/material.module';
import { dateFormatPipe } from './shared/date_format.pipe';
import { dateTimeFormatPipe } from './shared/date_time_format.pipe';

import { AuthService } from './shared/auth.service';
import { SnackBarService } from './shared/snackbar.service';
import { ServiceNcmService } from './shared/service_ncm.service';

import { UserCompanyService } from './user_companies/user_company.service';
import { AppInterceptor } from './core/app.interceptor';
import { UserComponent } from './users/user.component';
import { UserService } from './users/user.service';
import { UserDetailsComponent } from './users/user_details/user_details.component';
import { DeleteUserCompanyComponent } from './users/user_details/delete_user_company.component';
import { DeleteUserComponent } from './users/user_details/delete_user.component';
import { ProfileService } from './profiles/profile.service';
import { CompanyNcmComponent } from './company_ncms/company_ncm.component';
import { CompanyNcmService } from './company_ncms/company_ncm.service';
import { CompanyNcmDetailsComponent } from './company_ncms/company_ncm_details/company_ncm_details.component';
import { InsertAllCompanyNcmComponent } from './company_ncms/company_ncm_details/insert_all_company_ncm.component';
import { DeleteCompanyNcmComponent } from './company_ncms/company_ncm_details/delete_company_ncm.component';
import { ChangeStatusCompanyNcmComponent } from './company_ncms/company_ncm_details/change_status_company_ncm.component';
import { DebounceDirective } from './directives/debounce_directive';
import { CompanyCurrencyComponent } from './company_currencies/company_currency.component';
import { CompanyCurrencyService } from './company_currencies/company_currency.service';
import { CompanyCurrencyDetailsComponent } from './company_currencies/company_currency_details/company_currency_details.component';
import { DeleteCompanyCurrencyComponent } from './company_currencies/company_currency_details/delete_company_currency.component';
import { ChangeStatusCompanyCurrencyComponent } from './company_currencies/company_currency_details/change_status_company_currency.component';
import { CurrencyBaseService } from './currency_bases/currency_base.service';
import { CompanySettingComponent } from './company_settings/company_setting.component';
import { CompanySettingService } from './company_settings/company_setting.service';
import { ServiceCompaniesService } from './company_settings/service_companies.service';

import { NcmTaxComponent } from './ncm_taxes/ncm_tax.component';
import { NcmTaxService } from './ncm_taxes/ncm_tax.service';
import { NcmTaxDetailsComponent } from './ncm_taxes/ncm_tax_details/ncm_tax_details.component';
import { NcmTaxHistoricsComponent } from './ncm_taxes/ncm_tax_details/ncm_tax_historics.component';
import { NcmTaxEventsComponent } from './ncm_taxes/ncm_tax_details/ncm_tax_events.component';
import { CurrencyQuotationComponent } from './currency_quotations/currency_quotation.component';
import { CurrencyQuotationService } from './currency_quotations/currency_quotation.service';
import { CurrencyQuotationEventsComponent } from './currency_quotations/currency_quotation_details/currency_quotation_events.component';
import { NgxMatSelectSearchModule } from 'ngx-mat-select-search';
import { NgxPermissionsModule } from 'ngx-permissions';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent, SignInComponent, DashboardComponent, UserComponent, 
    UserDetailsComponent, DeleteUserCompanyComponent, DeleteUserComponent,
    CompanyNcmComponent, CompanyNcmDetailsComponent, DeleteCompanyNcmComponent,
    DebounceDirective, ChangeStatusCompanyNcmComponent,
    CompanyCurrencyComponent, CompanyCurrencyDetailsComponent, DeleteCompanyCurrencyComponent,
    ChangeStatusCompanyCurrencyComponent, CompanySettingComponent,
    NcmTaxComponent, NcmTaxDetailsComponent, NcmTaxHistoricsComponent,
    dateFormatPipe, dateTimeFormatPipe, NcmTaxEventsComponent, CurrencyQuotationComponent,
    CurrencyQuotationEventsComponent, InsertAllCompanyNcmComponent,
    UpdatePasswordComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    CoreModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    HttpModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MaterialModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    NgxMatSelectSearchModule,
    NgxPermissionsModule.forRoot()
  ],
  providers: [ 
    CurrencyQuotationService, NcmTaxService, 
    CompanySettingService, CurrencyBaseService, 
    CompanyCurrencyService, CompanyNcmService, Angular2TokenService, 
    SnackBarService, ProfileService, HttpClientModule, UserService, 
    AuthService, UserCompanyService, ServiceCompaniesService,
    ServiceNcmService,
  {
    provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
    useClass: AppInterceptor,
    multi: true,
  }],
  entryComponents: [
    UserDetailsComponent, DeleteUserCompanyComponent, DeleteUserComponent,
    CompanyNcmDetailsComponent, ChangeStatusCompanyNcmComponent,
    DeleteCompanyNcmComponent, CurrencyQuotationEventsComponent,
    CompanyCurrencyDetailsComponent, ChangeStatusCompanyCurrencyComponent,
    DeleteCompanyCurrencyComponent, NcmTaxDetailsComponent,
    NcmTaxHistoricsComponent, NcmTaxEventsComponent, InsertAllCompanyNcmComponent,

  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule {}
```

Is there a disavantage of using only one module? Should I separate in multiple?

Comment: depends of your business logic, differents  modules with combination of lazy loading mechanisms will allow you to split the code and download only the module that you need. if your user never access to one part of the code, this part never should be downloaded by the browser

Comment: @Ricardo So if I'm not using lazy loading, I guess it's not worth it to separate...

Comment: @GustavoGabriel why don't you use lazy loading? You should try to utilize it when you can. It improves user experience. Also, keeping everything in single module is not scalable. I would suggest you to create a module for each of root folder (i.e. company-settings.module, currency-quotations.module etc.)

Comment: @GustavoGabriel. Here is a link on how use lazy loading or add modules: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49621578/how-to-route-to-feature-module

Comment: Anecdote: our application had become so big that it took over 40 seconds to load as a monolith, unthrottled on localhost. _The vast_ majority of that time was spent parsing code and instantiating all the components, not downloading data. Lazy loading helps with _both_ concerns, so if you think your application will grow with time, figure out how to do module splitting and lazy loading now, when it's easy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a disavantage of using only one module? Should I separate in multiple?

This question feels like `why don't we write all of the code in a single file?`

You stated that,

> it is easy to understand and easy to do the routing

Well, for you it may be true (I doubt it). But keep in mind that, you do not write code mainly for computers, but for other people. Having a huge module complexifies your codebase and it would be hard for other people to get adjusted to it.

Please, read more about [Separation of Concerns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98734/what-is-separation-of-concerns)

Angular modules are great at SoC. You can have as many features modules as you need for different parts of your application. Having small modules makes it easy to test and scale your application. Also, you can utilize [Angular Lazy Loading Modules](https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules#lazy-loading-feature-modules) easily. You should eagerly try to use lazy loading even if you think you don't need it. It greatly improves user experience.

Also, check Angular guide for [Feature Modules](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#feature-modules)

You already have some sort of modular system (without `NgModule`s)

I suggest you create `NgModule`s for every root folder you have. I.e. `users.module`, `company_currencies.module` etc. Your application looks big as is now, it would get a lot messier in the future to split the application into different modules.

Comment: hi, what is SoC ?

Comment: @DrNio Separation of Concerns. I posted a link one line above.

Comment: Ok, you guys convinced me :) Lazy loading it is!

Comment: I'm glad you changed your mind :). You should read angular guide from head to bottom. It shows best practices for angular applications. We follow that guide at work :)

Answer (score 3):

It depends how big the application is. If you only have few components "describing" one function it is fine to keep one. So for example if you have a small public website with a front page, contact page etc. I don't see any reason to have multiple modules.

In most common cases Angular is used for larger web apps, with authentication and it is by the framework design much better to separate components in modules for encapsulation, lazy loading etc.