# Angular 4 error: "Could not resolve exrternal module from app module" with lazy loading

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, angular-module

External Angular app/module:

```
@NgModule({
declarations: [
    HelloComponent
],
imports: [
    CommonModule,
    UpgradeRoutingModule
],
exports: [],
providers: [],
bootstrap: []
})
export class UpgradeModule { }
```

UpgradeRoutingModule:

```
const upgradeRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: HelloComponent
    }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [ RouterModule.forChild(upgradeRoutes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class UpgradeRoutingModule { }
```

Routes in the main app:

```
export const ROUTES = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomePageComponent,
    data: {
        breadcrumbs: [],
        sortProductsBy: CONFIG.urlParams.sortProductsBy.alphabetical
    },
    resolve: {
        products: PropositionsResolver
    }
  },
  {
    path: 'childoo',
    loadChildren: '../mymodule/src/app/app.module#UpgradeModule'
  }
]
```

**loadChildren path:** the real path should come from **node_module**, but I was testing that module, trying to figure out why I'm getting that error while I'm serving the app.
The main app work well without that child path, but the weird thing is that it works also if I add the child path only after the app has been served (so while the app is running, obviously --watch is active)

Comment: You may be looking for an answer like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49621578/how-to-route-to-feature-module/49622371#49622371

Comment: Are you sure, your path `../mymodule/src/app/app.module` to `UpgradeModule` is correct? Because it ends with `app.module` file. If so, why module file name and module name are different? Any specific reason?

Comment: @AmitChigadani none specific reason, I wanted to put a different name, so that I could recognise in the routes