# How is multi-level routing made possible in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular2-routing, angular2-template, angular2-directives

As you can see from the image below, upon clicking on component (1), I want component (2) to load which is working perfectly fine. Now upon clicking component (2) I want component (3) to load. 
How can this be achieved??? Please help!!!!

The first image link contains the UI of the webpage.

The next 4 image links include my code.

[Web page display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HxX7l.png)

[app component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rWSxr.png)

[navigation component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ATxCN.png)

[home component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XbqQm.png)

[App module - Routes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FtXKK.png)

Comment: please check webpage link. try to share stackblitz

Comment: Please share the code instead of code images.

Comment: See this my answer on this link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49621578/how-to-route-to-feature-module