# Not able to make Single page application using angular 6?

Tags: angular

I am working on an application which is kinda  blogging website in which at homepage there will be list of articles  and once clicked on any article complete detail for that article  will open on same page by replacing the list of articles. 
WIth current code it opens the article detail at the bottom of page when i click on any article.
Here is what i have

**1.Index.html**

```
<header>
<app-root></app-root>
<footer>
```

2. **app.component.html**

   ```
   <div>
   <p>article 1</p>
   <a routerLink="/article1"  >Link to details for article1</a>
   </div>
   <div>
   <p>article 2</p>
   <a routerLink="/article2"  >Link to details for article2</a>
   </div>
     <router-outlet></router-outlet>
   ```

Comment: @TheHeadRush may be the title i have given is not correct..i know how to make SPA but im not sure how to do in this scinerio

Comment: My answer on this link may help you so you can have children routes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49621578/how-to-route-to-feature-module. See my profile and see how my app works.

Answer (score 2):

I would highly recommend walking through the [Tour Of Heros Tutorial for Angular](https://angular.io/tutorial).
It walks you through the basics of building an angular application.

The quickest way to build an Angular application is to use the CLI it's also the easiest way to learn it.   If you want to not use the CLI that is also an option but not something I would recommend when learning how it works.

To get started with the CLI:

1. Make Sure you have Node/NPM installed.
2. Then install the Angular CLI `npm install -g @angular/cli`
3. Then create a new application `ng new your-app-name`
4. Then you can use `ng serve -o` to compile the application and open a web browser, at that point you can attempt to make changes.

The navigation issues you are having are related to ["routing" the Tour of Heros Application Tutorial](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt5) also covers how this works in a step by step fashion.

You really need to separate your components here

app-component.html

```
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

article-list.html

```
<div>
<p>article 1</p>
<a routerLink="/article1"  >Link to details for article1</a>
</div>
<div>
<p>article 2</p>
<a routerLink="/article2"  >Link to details for article2</a>
</div>
```

This way you can display `article-list` through the route and then it will disappear when you display the article as desired.

Comment: thanks for your answer . i have been through tour-of-heroes but my case is different. What i want is if i click on any article among the list of article then this whole list of article should be replaced by the article detail.

Comment: you can use `*ngIf` to show programmatically the list of the articles and the single article details with a variable.

Comment: @NawnitSen please clarify your question above with additional details.    That was not clear from the original question.    You also don't seem to have the  RouterModule setup code in the question.   If you have not set up the RouterModule with the correct routes you won't be able to navigate

Comment: @RobertLove i have routerModule setup in my app..i added <router-outlet> at the end but when i clicked on any article it will open the article detail at the end of page where i have written <router-outlet>.

Comment: @JacopoSciampi that is  how i used to do in angularJS but i thought maybe there will be another way to do it in angular.

Comment: @RobertLove I have updated the question.Can you please take a look at it?

Comment: @NawnitSen I have updated my answer with more details.     I still feel your question is not clear on what you desire to have happen.

Comment: i'll try to explain...at homepage there is list of articles and for each article there is another page which has the article details. what i want is once i click on any article link, list of articles should disappear and at that place page for that article detail should appear. is it clear now?

Comment: @NawnitSen that is clear here in comments.   Update the question with that.   Then reread my answer as an option is presented in it.