# Angular 6 nested children routing not rendering view

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-guards

I am stuck in a place where the navigation works, but view is not working basically one component is mapped to two different routes:

**Component** is *example.component.ts*

**Routes** are

http://localhost:4200/manager/nav/example

http://localhost:4200/nav/valuation

Have two different modules and have there own routes defined

Navigation mecahnism: when user hits **manager** it loads its own component and then user can navigate to **manager>nav** and from nav user can naviagte to manager>nav>example

**manager.routing.ts**

```
{ path: 'manager', component: ManagerComponent , children:[
 { path: '', component: PortfolioManagerComponent },
 { path: 'nav', component: NavComponent},children: [
  { path: 'example', component: component:ExampleComponent}

] }
```

]
  }

**http://localhost:4200/manager/nav**
[image]

**http://localhost:4200/manager/nav/example**
[image: Issue view not change]

Route changed but view not render bascially its on manager view not on example view

But when i use the route nav and than hit example it loads the original page and nav has its own module and routing

**nav.routing.ts**

```
  { path: 'nav', component: NavComponent, children: [
  { path: '', component: PropertyComponent},
  { path: 'example, ', component:ExampleComponent}
 ]
```

**Showing right views**

[image]

[image]

When i use the route **http://localhost:4200/manager/nav/example** till http://localhost:4200/manager/nav the view changes and when I naviagte to  **http://localhost:4200/manager/nav/example** the same view remains its is not loading the view but route changes

You can see first two Images to view the routing  and last two images the right view

Comment: My advice is to use lazy loading and the link below may give you the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49621578/how-to-route-to-feature-module. I use this lazy loading throughout my large scale application eCommerce similar to yours. See my profile. Good luck in finding the solutions to your issues.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is you use Angular's default path matching strategy, which is **prefix**. It means that Angular will use the first route it finds in your router module that starts with the specified segment of your route.
And an empty path is a special case as all paths starts with an empty path. So in this example **nav** and **example** both start with an empty path and Angular will navigate to the component that is associated with empty path and that is PortfolioManagerComponent.

```
{ path: 'manager', component: ManagerComponent , children:[
 { path: '', component: PortfolioManagerComponent },
 { path: 'nav', component: NavComponent},children: [
  { path: 'example', component: component:ExampleComponent}

] }
```

What you need to do is changing your matching strategy to **full** by adding the **pathMatch** attribute to your route:

```
{ path: 'manager', component: ManagerComponent , children:[
    { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', component: PortfolioManagerComponent },
    { path: 'nav', component: NavComponent},children: [
    { path: 'example', component: component:ExampleComponent}

    ] }
```

More info in the docs: https://angular.io/api/router/Routes#matching-strategy