# Angular Routes: Problem defining a NotFoundComponent with multiple routings files

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular6

I am creating a NotFoundComponent so that every non-existing url, a friendly page will apear to the user.

My Angular 6 project has 5 features(CRUDL):

CompanyComponent,
EmployeeComponent,
BranchComponent,
BenefitsComponent,
MainComponent

Each component have it own .module and .routing, for example the company.routing.ts defines the route like this:

```
    export const routes: Routes = [
    {
      path: "branch",
      component: EmptyComponent,
    }
    ...
    @NgModule({
imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(routes),
    ...
```

it also defines its childrens, like path: "branch/:id".

So, i have no problem with the way i built the routing.

The problem I am facing now is the way I can define a path to the NotFoundComponent.

Because I don't have a single file where I define my routes, if I put the definition of the /404 page on the on the bottom of routers definition in the main.routing.ts, every other route defined on the features(like the company.routing.ts) will be redirected to the /404, since angular uses the first match strategy.

Things i tried so far:

on the main.routing.ts:

```
export const routes: Routes = [
{
    path: "main",
    component: MainComponent,
},
{
    path: "404",
    resolve: {
        routeTitle: TitleResolver,
    },
    component: NotFoundComponent,
},
{
    path: "",
    pathMatch: "full",
    redirectTo: "/main",
},
{
    path: "**",
    redirectTo: "/404",
}
```

if I put this way, when I try accessing the route /company (defined in the company.routing.ts) it will be redirected to the /404.

I also tried defining it on any a routing of one of my features, like on the company.routing.ts

```
{
    path: "**",
    redirectTo: "/404",
}
```

Than, a funny thing happened, if I define this piece of code on the benefits.routing.ts, i can access */benefits* but */branch*, */employee* and the rest of the routes will be redirected to /404.

[image: project structure]

if I define it on branch, I can access */benefits*, */branch* but */employee* and the rest of the routes will be redirected to /404.

I could just place this code on the last feature loaded and it would work but I would like to know if I can solve this with another approach, can't I define a route that I want to be the last one loaded?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Need to see how you load your other modules using route - stackblitz will do great - please add

Comment: @Gustavo. The link below may solve your issues:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49621578/how-to-route-to-feature-module/49622371#49622371. It explains lazy loading and children routes. Each module has its own <router-outlet>. You can have lots of modules and you should import them like a tree structure.

Comment: my problem is because I lazy load modules, but I can't change the way I import stuffs because otherwise it will be a performance loss, can't find any work around yet, I probably would need to define my routes elsewhere and import them.